# I am creating my own guessing name but the program doesn't start

Tags: python

What might I be doing wrong in this program? I recently started with Python.

```
##number guesser generator
import random


def main():


    print("welcome to the number guessing game!")


    print("You will receive three guesses!")

    print("Choose a number between 1 and 100")

    randomnumbergenerator()

    userinput()

    winorlose()






def randomnumbergenerator():
    
random.seed(0)
   
 randomnumber = random.randint(1,100)

    return randomnumber



def userinput():
 
   answer1 = int(input('what is your 1st guess?'))

    answer2 = int(input('what is your 2nd guess?'))

    answer3 = int(input('what is your 3rd guess?'))



    answers = answer1, answer2, answer3
    return answers

def winorlose(randomnumber, answers):

    while randomnumber != answers:

        print('You lose! The correct answer equals' + randomnumber)

        if randomnumber == answers:

            print("You picked the correct answer! The answer was " + randomnumber)

    return winorlose()
```

Comment: Do you ever call `main`? It isn't a special function like it is in other languages. It isn't called automatically.

Comment: the `def main()` is just a normal function as others. you should trigger your program with`__name__` == `"__main__"` check, or, just invoke `main()` method directly.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty noob as well, but it looks as though you're building the script in a class type method but haven't added the class.

At the moment the program just runs through and creates all the functions ready for instances to be called, but you've called them within the main function which itself doesn't get called. If you were to do something like this:

```
class randomGenerator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.main()

    def main(self):

        print("welcome to the number guessing game!")


        print("You will receive three guesses!")

        print("Choose a number between 1 and 100")

        self.randomnumbergenerator()

        self.userinput()

        self.winorlose()

    def randomnumbergenerator(self):

        random.seed(0)

        randomnumber = random.randint(1,100)

        return randomnumber

    def userinput(self):

        answer1 = int(input('what is your 1st guess?'))

        answer2 = int(input('what is your 2nd guess?'))

        answer3 = int(input('what is your 3rd guess?'))



        answers = answer1, answer2, answer3
        return answers

    def winorlose(self, randomnumber, answers):

        while randomnumber != answers:

            print('You lose! The correct answer equals' + randomnumber)

            if randomnumber == answers:

                print("You picked the correct answer! The answer was " + randomnumber)

        return winorlose()


run = randomGenerator()
```

then at least it will start and you can troubleshoot more. I recommend you research classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

The function `main` is just another normal function. Python has no concept of a "main" function. You need to call the `main()` function manually like so

```py
# Check if file was executed as the "main" file
# This is optional, but it ensures that if you import this file as a module,
# the main function isn't invoked
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main() # Call the main function
```